# Cancel PHP script with XHR?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have with your help:

```
function send(){
  $.get("/site/send.php", function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
}
```

In site/send.php I have:

```
for($=0;$i++;$i<1000)
    sleep(1);
}
    echo "OK";
```

Next I have in my js file:

```
send();
$("#click").click(function(){
  window.stop(); // this cancel XHR
  $.get("/site/reset.php", function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
})
```

and in reset.php:

```
echo "RESET";
```

window.stop(); cancel my XHR but this still doesnt working OK. i cancel XHR, but still i must wait for **sleep(1000)** in function send(). This doesnt return anything, but still continues to execute. Only if sleep is > 1000 then **/site/reset.php** begins to execute.

how can i in this example cancel PHP function?

is possible check in PHP file check if XHR still isset?

Comment: You can't cancel a running php script unless it periodically checks for an exit conditions. Cancelling the XHR request does nothing.

Comment: so how can i make this correctly?

Comment: and why would you even try to do that? Explain what you want to do and maybe you get a way better solution do achieve it.

Comment: 1) make the php script check a condition (e.g. content of an helper file), if 1, abort, else continue running. 2) on button click send an ajax request to some other php-handler, which will set the contents of the helper file to 1.

Comment: but in this example still one script PHP is running and i can't execute new script

Comment: so basically the problem is, that your webserver (apache/IIS/something) does only handle one request at a time. If a second request comes in the first is still running, then the second one has to wait till the first is finished?

Comment: yes, exactly. i use Apache. is possible to change this?

Comment: Im very sure it is. I dont know how exactly, but you should be looking for an apache setting not for cancelling execution of a script for sure!

Comment: @Flo wouldn't accessing two pages at the same time mess with the session? :) as far as I know, the reason only one script can run at a time is because the rest will wait for it to finish accessing the session file..

Answer (score 2):

Any of the following may work:

```
ignore_user_abort(false);
```

---

```
for ($=0;$i++;$i<1000) {
   if (connection_aborted()) break;
```

---

```
for ($=0;$i++;$i<1000) {
   if (connection_status() != CONNECTION_NORMAL) break;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have root access on the php server, if you are on linux, you can just execute some bash command, using `:

```
echo `ps -A`;
```

get you a list of all running processes on the machine, then if you know the user apache uses to execute scripts, you can then 
    echo `ps -u user`;

After you identify the correct PID you can kill it with:

```
echo `kill PID`;
```

ex

```
echo `kill 1023`;
```

or

// I do not know if this works exactly this way
   eval('echo `kill '.$_GET['PID'].'`;');

All of this executed in a different php script, made exactly for the purpose to kill other scripts at command.

You can use AJAX to request this kind of jobs from the script mentioned about.

Also you  can make php file write to the client it's own PID (google for the write function, it looks very much like the c one) and then the javascript can send that PID directly to that killer script to command an execution stop for some script.

EDIT 1:

you can get the running script PID with this function:

```
getmypid();
```

and you can save it in a file, or better in a session variable

```
$_SESSION[__FILE__] = getmypid();
```

and to stop a file from running, you can call a page like this (killer.php):

```
<?php
// security verifications, etc
/*

*/ 
session_start();
$f = $_SESSION[$_GET['file']];
echo `kill $f`;

?>
```

It is dangerous although.

I do not know the exact commands to execute, or if you have or not that kind of control, or even if you are on a linux system. If you want I can research it a bit.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#click").click(function(){
  //window.stop(); 
  return false;
```

Comment: "how can i in this example cancel **PHP** function?"

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with what the user is asking. This simply stops the click event from propogating.