# Need to cancel external javascript load because of socket pool limit

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I have a system where I inject a script tag into the dom.
The browser tries to load the script url, which is actually a long-post to a Tornado server.
I'm trying to implement an "abort" feature, where I stop the long poll. I need to do this because I am long-polling multiple different URL's which eventually exhausts the browser's socket pool for my server.
I have tried removing the specific script node from the DOM, but the browser is stubborn and continues waiting for a response from the server.

**Is it possible to tell the browser to stop trying to load a resource (specifically a javascript file) once I've included it into the DOM?**

Comment: Nop, its not possible. Maybe you should split the long-post in short chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try an asynchoronous abort "mission" and kill the pid of the request. Thsi kind of tehnique is very similar to this post [Cancel PHP script with XHR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473668/cancel-php-script-with-xhr/8475000#8475000) so you could run an extra ajax call for an abort which handles it like in the post above. Happy new year!

Comment: What an ugly hack. But it looks like it cannot be done in a better way.